# Legitimate usage of "like"?

Tags: as-like

Is this a legitimate sentence:

> I look bad like you.

Maybe with a comma after "bad"?

I'm aware of the alternative "I look as bad as you." - just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a perfectly grammatically legitimate sentence, but it's not synonymous with "I look as bad as you".

> I look bad like you

means "I look bad, too".

> I look as bad as you

means "I look bad to the same extent that you do."

Comment: Would the comma be wrong?

Comment: No, it would not be wrong.  It shifts the meaning a bit, emphasizing that "you look bad".  It can then be used like, "I look bad.  But then, you look bad too, so no problem."